# What values can take the number of elements of the union?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A_1, ..., A_n$ some different not empty sets. $| A_i | = k$, for $\forall i$. What values can take the number of elements of the union $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$, if $|\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i| \leq m \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Have you tried at least the extreme cases like "all sets disjoint" or "an increasing sequence of sets"? between all values are possible… show this!

Comment: Where is $m$ ????

Comment: $m$ is natural number and $m \geq k$

Comment: What is 'it' in "if it is less than m"?.

Comment: I correcred the condition

Comment: @Gono, the number of objects of each set is the same, so they can not be "an increasing sequence of sets"

Comment: Yeah… so much edits :-) But still my hint is valuable… just the "extreme cases" changed. "Different" means at least one element differs so still there are two extreme cases. The first one "Always one element changes so you get $k + (n-1)$ as a final result or if always all items differes you get $nk$ elements for the resulting set… and still no own ansatz from your side…

Comment: @Gono Yes, I agree with you. But how now to prove this in the general case, that is, for any sets $ A_1, ..., A_n: | \bigcup A_i | \geq n + k - 1 $

Comment: As usual for such statements… induction. Although this is kind of "obvious".

Comment: Although this statement is incorrect. For example, $ A_1 = \{1,2,3\}, A_2 = \{1,2,4\}, A_3 = \{1,3,4\} $. Then: $ A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 = 4 < n + k - 1 = 3 + 3 -1 = 5 $

Comment: I think I found the answer. Let $r = \min_{\forall A = \{A_1, ..., A_n\}: | A_i | = k \forall i, A_i! = A_j \forall i, \forall j} \{| \bigcup_ {i = 1}^n A_i | \}$. Then $ C_r ^ k \geq n $. That is, $ r = \min \{r \in \mathbb {N}: r \geq k, C_r ^ k \geq n \} $

Comment: removed xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: What's also wrong (as my thought were)… the smallest number is obviously $k$ if $n=1$